# Appending text in <a>-tags with Javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I now that I can insert text to `<div>` tag by :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething(){
    var lbl = document.getElementById('messageLabel');
    lbl.innerHTML = "I just did something.";    
  }  
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <div id="messageLabel"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="doSomething();" />

  </div>
```

**My question:** how can I append text to to a link?

Examples not working [1](http://pastebin.com/m61d3df96) and [2](http://pastebin.com/m13a66ac9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the example  you posted above, try using the code below instead. I changed the id of the div tag to be different from the link you're trying to change and changed the code to modify the href of anchor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Javascript Debugging with Firebug</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addLink(){
    var anchor = document.getElementById('link');
    anchor.href += "Dsi7x-A89Mw";
  }  
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <div id="linkdiv"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="addLink();" />

  <a id="link" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=">Click here</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: really cool, but it appends "Dsi7x-A89Mw" to the end of "Click here", and not "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".

Comment: In that case you want to use anchor.href ... i've amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('anchorID');
anchor.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML + " I just did something.";
```

Should add "I just did something." to your current anchor text

Comment: The example you posted has two elements with he same id.  id is meant to be unique in a page, try using a different id for your a element.

Answer (score 2):

innerText or textContent can be used to access the text of a tag:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('something');
anchor.innerText += "some text";    

var anchor = document.getElementById('something');
anchor.textContent += "some text";
```

However, those are not cross-browser, so you would probably be better off using innerHTML:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('something');
anchor.innerHTML += "some text";
```

See this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Comment: It will not append, but rather replace the text.

Comment: innerText is not supported by all browsers.